# sqlite not returning(select clause) data in the order data was inserted from NSArray

Tags: sql, iphone, sqlite, nsarray

i am in phase of learning sqlite for ios integration.
My question is ho to get order of row to be same as at the time of sql-insert?
guys i have two NSArray holding some data.I am inserting them in table like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayFieldName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[data objectForKey:@"arrayFieldNameKey"]] ;

NSMutableArray *arrayFieldValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[data objectForKey:@"arrayFieldValueKey"]] ;
```

the log is as:

```
Printing description of arrayFieldName:
```

(

Date Of Birth,

republic,

Marriage,

Currency,

Incentive,

Interview Dates,

hobbies,

Tanki Online,

skills,

Sal Range

)

Printing description of arrayFieldValue:
(

2014-04-13,

Rep26,

2014-03-17,

56,

58,

Feb 20,

,

Thunder,

|#|PHP|#|Java|#|Python|#|,

|#|0 - 10k|#|10k - 20k|#|20k -30k|#|

)

above log is as expected.
 now i perform select to get fieldName and fieldValue:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM customer_custom_fields where customer_id=? AND deleted = 0", custId];
while ([rs next])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dic setObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"field_name"] forKey:@"field_name"];
    [dic setObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"field_value"] forKey:@"field_value"];
    [dic setObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"deleted"] forKey:@"deleted"];
    [dic setObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"update_date"] forKey:@"update_date"];
    [arr addObject:dic];
}


return arr;
```

and the result looks like this:
[image: unexpected order of rows in attached image]

for example currency become first and date of birth become second..

any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thats due to you are using NSMutableDictionary which stores data in not in order. for that you can create your model class eg. name Customer and add properties like currency float , date of birth as date or string etc etc.

Comment: if you see that select query prior to save data in mutable dictionary it's already unordered, hence no matter i take nsmutable/model class